# Passing instance a value manually causes "incompatible types" error

Tags: java, methods, boolean, conditional-statements, instance

```java
public class Order {
    boolean isFilled;
    double billAmount;
    String shipping;

     public Order(boolean filled, double cost, String shippingMethod) {
        if (cost > 24.00) {
            System.out.println("High value item!");
        }
        isFilled = filled;
        billAmount = cost;
        shipping = shippingMethod;
    }

    public void ship() {
          if (isFilled) {
              System.out.println("Shipping");
              System.out.println("Shipping cost: " + calculateShipping());
        } else {
            System.out.println("Order not ready");
        }
    }

    public double calculateShipping() {

        if (shipping ="Regular") {
            return 0;
        } else if (shipping = "Express") {
            return 1.75;
        } else {
            return .50;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // do not alter the main method!
        Order book = new Order(true, 9.99, "Express");
        Order chemistrySet = new Order(false, 72.50, "Regular");

        book.ship();
        chemistrySet.ship();
    }
}
```

The code above causes this error:

```
   Order.java:26: error: incompatible types: String cannot be converted to boolean
   if (shipping="Regular") 



{
                ^
   Order.java:28: error: incompatible types: String cannot be converted to boolean
    } else if (shipping = "Express") {
                        ^
   2 errors
```

Comment: did my answer below help you? please accept it if it works

Comment: someone is talking out here, accept my answer if it solved the problem, be helpful 
as I made effort to detect your problem, you only have to make one click to reward my help, be a helpful member of this community, don't ignore this please https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: can you answer my calls?

Answer (score 1):

first of all let's see the difference between `=` and `==` in Java

- ‘`=`’ is the assignment operator in Java.
- ‘`==`’ is the comparison operator, and returns true if one side is
  equal to the other.

In your case you are trying two compare two variables, so you don't have to use the assignment operator `=`.
And since `String` is not a primitif type (is a class), you can't use `==` which is used for reference comparison between objects (address comparison), so you need to use the method `equals()` which compares between two objects of type `String`. If any character is not matched, it returns false. If all characters are matched, it returns true.

to solve this, you just have to:

- replace `if (shipping="Regular")` with `if (shipping.equals("Regular"))`
- and `else if (shipping = "Express")` with `else if (shipping.equals("Express"))`

so your `calculateShipping()` method will be as follow

```
public double calculateShipping() {

        if (shipping.equals("Regular")) {
            return 0;
        } else if (shipping.equals("Express")) {
            return 1.75;
        } else {
            return .50;
        }
}
```